# How make an object that's shared across the entire application in play framework (1.x)?

Tags: java, rest, playframework, playframework-1.x, application-scope

I want to make one instance of an object across the entire Play Application. I don't think `static` will work because Play uses many classloaders to load the same class many times (I confirmed this with a heap analysis).

Is there something like `InitialContext` resources to store and retrieve an object instance across the entire app?