# How make a Singleton across all ClassLoaders?

Tags: java, playframework, singleton

I've tried all the suggested solutions including:

- http://snehaprashant.blogspot.com/2009/01/singleton-pattern-in-java.html
- [How to create a JVM-global Singleton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23445434/how-to-create-a-jvm-global-singleton)

But none of these seem to work. They either are not truly Singletons across all ClassLoaders (the first link above) and result in different instances on application reload (I'm using Play Framework 1.3.x which reloads classes upon code change and recompile), or they require the classes to be on the System classpath.

Is there a solution for this? I want the class to be loaded once and even after classes are reloaded with new ClassLoaders, to still have the same *one* instance of that class.

Is this possible?

Comment: If you can't put the class on the system classpath then I believe you will ALWAYS have a race condition in the case where the singleton is being instantiated by multiple threads at the same time.  There has to be something in a known root position that can be identified statically to serve as the anchor, or at least a monitor to prevent the race condition.

Comment: Why do you need that? What is the problem here?

Comment: Is this a duplicate of [How make an object that's shared across the entire application in play framework (1.x)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37909439/how-make-an-object-thats-shared-across-the-entire-application-in-play-framework)

Comment: why is it an issue to have it in the Extensions ClassLoader? For me it is the only way

Comment: @NicolasFilotto How do you programmatically load it there? or do you put the classes in that directory?

Comment: put your jar in JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext